# Set Eslint configurations to minimum in React

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslintrc

I need to change Eslint warnings. If there is a error, react will not render. I need to change that to just a warning message and render the application. Also use the auto formatting.

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import eslint from "vite-plugin-eslint";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), eslint()],
});
```

> Above code is included in vite.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:react/jsx-runtime",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
  ],
  ignorePatterns: ["dist", ".eslintrc.cjs"],
  parserOptions: { ecmaVersion: "latest", sourceType: "module" },
  settings: { react: { version: "18.2" } },
  plugins: ["react-refresh"],
  rules: {
    "react-refresh/only-export-components": [
      "warn",
      { allowConstantExport: true },
    ],
  },
};
```

> This code is included in .eslintrc.cjs

In error it says

Click outside, press Esc key, or fix the code to dismiss. You can also
disable this overlay by setting **server.hmr.overlay** to **false** in
**vite.config.js.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
    rules: {
    // ... your rules
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ["*.js", "*.jsx", "*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      rules: {
        "react-refresh/only-export-components": [
          "warn",
          { allowConstantExport: true },
        ],
        // Add other rules you want to treat as warnings
      },
    },
  ],
  emitWarning: true, // Emit warnings instead of errors
```

Setting emitWarning to **true** ,it instructs ESLint to treat potential problems as warnings instead of errors, it allow your app to render while still highlighting issues for you to address.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But emitWarning: true didn't work. Is there any other way?